# How can I delete from cursor to start in terminal (delete, not cut)

Tags: command-line, bash

There are many answers pointing out that I can cut (kill) text in the terminal with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> like [this one of Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679776/how-do-i-clear-delete-the-current-line-in-terminal)

I often feel it is inconvenient to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>. Imagine this scenario:

1. I type a long command A `longlonglonglonglonglonglong`
2. Suddenly I realise I need do another thing first, so I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> to cut and (save) the current command
3. I type command B `wrongwrongwrongwrongwrongwrong`
4. Suddenly I realise I don't need command B, what I need is C,
5. So I need to delete the current command, but I *don't* want <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>, because that would overwrite command A with B.
6. Have to crazily press <kbd>backspace</kbd> to delete B.

I need <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>, but also need another command to only delete, not cut.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need to paste command B anywhere later, you can do this:

While on point 3 in your list, you can type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. This will abort the command you are currently typing and you get a new clean prompt:

```
$ foofooofoofoo^C
$
```

If you do need command B later, you can make use of the "middle-button-paste". To do this, you can select the text with the mouse and later paste it by clicking the mouse wheel or both mouse buttons simultaneously.